# Jquery Mouse event toggle effect for a div is bouncing even the mouse event exit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Jquery mouse enter and leave events for toggle effect to  div in html page

code is as follows

html code

```
<div class="platform_solutions map_link" id="microsoft_link">

      <h3>Heading One</h3>
     </div>
     <div class="testing map_link" id="opensource_link" >

       <h3>Heading Two</h3>
     </div>

     <div class="branding_services map_link" id="verification_link">

      <h3>Heading Three</h3>
     </div>
     <div class="corporate_profile map_link" id="branding_link">

       <h3>Heading Four</h3>
</div>




<div id="microsoft_link1" style="display:none; padding-bottom:20px; float:left;" class="map_data">
<h4>Heading one</h4>
<p>  Test data</p>
</div>
<div id="opensource_link1" style="display:none; padding-bottom:20px; float:left;" class="map_data">
<h4>Heading Two</h4>
<p> Test data two</p>
</div>
<div id="verification_link1" style="display:none; padding-bottom:20px; float:left;" class="map_data">
<h4>Heading Three</h4>
 <p> Test data xussfsf</p>
</div>
<div id="branding_link1" style="display:none; padding-bottom:20px; float:left;" class="map_data">
<h4>Test Heading</h4>
<p> Test data sfs </p>
</div>
```

Jquery Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(function() {


 $('.map_link').mouseenter(function(){
      event.preventDefault();

    var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#"+currentId+"1").slideToggle(); 
     $("#"+currentId+"1").css('display','block');
  }).mouseleave(function(){
       event.preventDefault();
   var currentId1 = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#"+currentId1+"1").slideToggle(); 


  });



});




});​
```

The code is working fine. But if we move the mouse from on heading to other heading fast. It's creating bouncing effect

Comment: You have two `document.ready` functions that are doing the exact same thing, and you're referrencing `event` inside the function without using `event` as a parameter ( `function(event) {...}`, should work in IE without it though ), and what you're missing is probably just some [**stop()**](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) 's

Answer (score 1):

Try this Please: **Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/XXTgW/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/XXTgW/1/

3 things to note :

- to use events pass it via `funciton(event)`
- http://api.jquery.com/stop/
- Added the `hide` for the data_map

Hope it fits the cause `:)`

**Code**

```
$(function() {


    $('.map_link').hover(function(event) {
        $('.map_data').hide();       
        var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#" + currentId + "1").stop(true, true).slideToggle();
    }, function(event) {
        $('.map_data').hide();
        var currentId1 = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#" + currentId1 + "1").stop(true, true).slideToggle();

    });


});​
```